# Does report Builder Supports OE 11.3?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

We have upgraded our database and application to OE11.3. We need to configure Report Builder in our application. Does Report Builder support oe 11.3? Where can I find the report libraries for our server?

I am not able to see any Report Builder procedures files (.p's) in the installation directory.

> is report builder a third party tool?
>   does report builder library files  not included in ot11.3
>   Where can i find report engine files in oe11.3 version?Please tell me the directory where its installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went through a similar issue when we upgraded from 9.1 D to 10.1 C. Report builder was no longer supported. However, you were able to use the report builder runtime and connect to a V10 database on the fly. This worked but if any changes needed made to the report in the prl file you would have to have a replicated v9 database that report builder connected to. This work but was flaky and we had so many problems with it.

Another solution is looking into integrating iReports into progress and use that as a replace or some other solution. iReports are essentially xml document storing the report information and then you will have to integrate some progress into java code to display the report in code or possibly just use it's report server instead.

Answer (score 0):

Report Builder was removed already in version 10, so no it's not available in OE 11.3.

> The Report Builder Design module will no longer be included in OpenEdge 10 but the Report Builder Runtime Engine will still be present for purposes of backwards compatibility.

Source: http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P57660

According to the link above it's still possible to run reports created in earlier versions, see this entry in the knowledgebase: [enter link description here](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P19277?popup=true)

Answer (score 0):

Report Builder "design" was discontinued with version 10.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P49272

However, http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000047285 refers to an issue with RB execution engine in 11.3 and indicates that it does indeed work with that release (although there is a problem with the OE 64 bit windows release and missing registry keys).